# Yammer Embed breaking existing JavaScript starting 9/30/2014

Tags: javascript, yammer

Has anyone else been experiencing issues with Yammer embed breaking their JS this morning.  We have several different applications spanning across different technologies (SharePoint, IBM, etc) that has been working for months but this morning we're seeing a lot of "Object Doesn't Support this method" errors.  Removing the embed scripts resolve the issues.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a discussion forum. If you have a specific question about a particular issue, then please phrase it as such and provide all relevant information needed to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had this issue. It appears that Yammer is interfering with jQuery. We fixed it my including Yammer script tags before jQuery script tags/Script links.

Move these before any mention of jQuery:

```
<script id='YammerScript' src='https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script id='YammerScript2' src='https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```